# Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/Path] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

Tags: java, rest

Can anyone please help in resolving the below null pointer exception when tried to hit with the postman application. Below are the resource class,web.xml,pom.xml class. Exception is thrown at this line "return commonManager.calculateFixedDeposit" in resource class

On debuging the code it is seen that it is due to this

```
/**
 * Constructs a InvocationTargetException with a target exception.
 *
 * @param target the target exception
 */
public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
    super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
    this.target = target;
}
```

Resource class

```
 package com.bank.resource;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import com.bank.beans.Deposit;
    import com.bank.beans.DepositResponse;
    import com.bank.common.CommonManager;
    import com.bank.common.Constants;

    @Named
    @Path(Constants.API)
    public class FixedDepositResource {

        @Resource
        CommonManager commonManager;

        @POST
        @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        @Path(Constants.FIXED_DEPOSIT)
        public DepositResponse fixedDepositResult(Deposit deposit) {

            return commonManager.calculateFixedDeposit(deposit.getPrincipal(),
                    deposit.getRateOfInterest(), deposit.getNoOfDays());

        }
    }
```

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>bankapplication</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.bank</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Error

```
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Apr 03, 2016 8:44:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
    Apr 03, 2016 8:44:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Apr 03, 2016 8:44:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 2327 ms
    Apr 03, 2016 8:44:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/bankapplication] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.bank.resource.FixedDepositResource.fixedDepositResult(FixedDepositResource.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>bankapplication</groupId>
  <artifactId>bankapplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <dependencies>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>  <!-- make sure the jersey version 
                                  matches the one you are using -->
</dependency>

</dependencies>



  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please help on this as I struck with this for the past two days

Comment: try to enter full package name in this param `<param-value>com.bank</param-value>` --> `<param-value>com.bank.resource</param-value>`

Comment: Tried however it not worked. The problem in my case able to go to the resource class where as it is failing while executing this method in calculateFixedDeposit in FixedDepositResource,

Comment: any solution for this issue? i am also facing same.